# How to add missing collation?

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, collation

i am executing the following query

> USE [master] GO ALTER DATABASE [mydatabase] COLLATE utf8_general_ci GO

and it's giving me the following error message :

> Msg 448, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Invalid collation
>   'utf8_general_ci'.

how can i add the collation utf8_general_ci to my library?

i am using the sql server management studio , and i want a database that accepts multiple languages

PS : I prefer not to use the nvarchar.

Comment: I don't think you can alter to a utf8 collation.  I've voted to move this question to dba stackexchange, as you'll get a better response there.

Comment: nvarchar and collation are different kind of things - nvarchar is data field type, collation is ruleset for sorting and comparing string values. You have to set collation (either implicitly or explicitly) for all string types, be these chars, varchars or their unicode brothers. To use multiple languages, you need unicode char field types (nchar, nvarchar etc) anyway. If you need to use collations for multiple languages, then you have to use collate clause in queries for searcing, sorting etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible to use collations returned by the `fn_helpcollations()` table function.

Oh, and MS SQL Server does not support UTF-8 in any way. Unless you are willing to store your strings in varbinary columns, of course.